# SSM Command never finishes executing. Any way to signal its end based on stdout?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js, aws-ssm

I'm trying to start a minecraft server by sending some commands to an EC2 instance using the AWS-SDK for javascript.

```
ssm.sendCommand({
  DocumentName: "AWS-RunShellScript",
  InstanceIds: ["ec2-instance-id"],
  TimeoutSeconds: 3600,
  Parameters: {
    commands: ['cd /home/ec2-user/minecraft/server', 'screen -S mc_server', 'java -Xmx3G -Xms3G -jar server-1-18.jar nogui']
  }}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("\nError:", err);
    } else {
      console.log("\nSuccess: ", data);
    }
  }
);
```

The command works correctly and I'm able to connect to the server after some waiting. The detail that bothers me is that the last command (`java -Xmx3G -Xms3G -jar server-1-18.jar nogui`) never finishes executing because it continously logs the different server events until the server is stopped manually. However, when the server finishes loading it prints to the stdout something like:

> Done! Finished in xxx seconds.

I would like to track the command stdout and signal the SSM executor to mark the command as finished, after that line is shown. I need to do this, because to stop the server properly, I need to re-attach the screen and then send the command `/stop`, but because the previous command is still running, it returns an error.

My overall goal is to start the server with a script, and then be able to stop it properly. I know I could just stop the instance to stop the server, but this could lead to corrupted chunks in my world. Maybe there is a better way to do this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What if you kill the ssm command as soon as it's launched(with a script which checks the jar file and send you an sns) and then with another command you can reattach to that screen and send `/stop`?

Comment: How can you check the jar file itself? That would be useful.

Comment: The easiest way will be to find a port which is opened by an application. In your case let's suppose it listens on port 2323, you can do `ps aux| grep 2323` and then with `echo $?` you can know if the port is opened. If the result of `echo $?` is 0, it's open else your service is not running. One can have a better solution but at the moment I can only think of this.

Comment: That is very interesting. I will try it out! See how it does